# KeystoneJS Cloudinary image upload

Tags: express, mongoose, cloudinary, keystonejs

I am using the latest version of `KeystoneJS` and have a form working to add a record to the database.
I'm having trouble getting image uploads to work.

My model conatains:

```
heroImage: { type: Types.CloudinaryImage, autoCleanup : true },
```

My form includes:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="heroImage" name="heroImage_upload" className='field-upload'>
```

and my middleware for saving the form simply includes:

```
view.on('post', {action: 'save'}, function(next) 
{
    var newProperty = new Property.model(req.body);

    console.log(newProperty);
    newProperty.save(function(err, body) 
    {});
});
```

which works great for all field's except the file upload.

I've tried adding:

```
    newProperty.heroImage = req.files['heroImage'];
```

which leaves `heroImage` as null.

I also tried creating a `cloudinaryImage` but this causes an error:

```
var img = new CloudinaryImage(req.files['heroImage']);
```

It all works fine when I use the `KeystoneJS` admin dashboard to upload images. Can someone please explain how I should use the `cloudinaryImage` field type in my own form?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but there is a note at the bottom of the docs:
http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-cloudinaryimage

"Remember that if you are uploading images to a `CloudinaryImage` field using an HTML form, you need to specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `form` tag."

Have you included that in your form?

## Update:

So, the following should work, assuming your model is called MyModel, and your form data uses the same object keys as your model. (i.e. the image for your `heroImage` field should be provided as `heroImage` in the POST data).

```
var MyModel = keystone.list('MyModel');

view.on('post', {action: 'save'}, function(next) 
{
   var item = new MyModel.model();
   data = req.body;
   item.getUpdateHandler(req).process(data, function(err) {
      // Handle error
   }
}
```

Keystone should then handle all the specific cloudinary stuff internally.

Comment: Yes I have a multipart form. In fact it works fine if I use `getUpdateHandler(req).process(req.body, function)` on a property object, however this causes other issues with validation. I would like to use the `save()` method, but think it needs a bit more to turn the uploaded file into a `CloudinaryImage` object to upload it to Cloudinary

Comment: Hmmm, not sure then I'm afraid. You could try something along the lines of

`var cloudinary = require('cloudinary'); cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.files['heroImage'], function(result) { ...});`


inside your `view.on('post'` function. You might also have to pass your cloudinary config options to this to get it to work.

Comment: If that works, you'll also need to tell you keystone model where the image is on cloudinary. Something like setting the `path` on your model to the `result` from cloudinary. This should be exactly what the update handler is doing for you though. What kind of validation errors were you getting?

Comment: Looking at `getUpdateHandler` it seems it calls `getRequestHandler(item, req, paths, callback)` of the `CloudinaryImage` but there's no documentation to say what `item` or `paths` are supposed to be, or how to call it.

Comment: `property.heroImage.getRequestHandler(` gives the error `property.heroImage.getRequestHandler is not a function`

Comment: How about `heroImage.updateItem`? If the data you pass this is a file, it should upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with `cloudinary.v2`

**untested keystone**

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(base64_file_data, (err, result) => {

  var newMyModel = new MyModel.model(model_data);

  newMyModel.image = result;

  let updater = newMyModel.getUpdateHandler(req);

  updater.process(newMyModel, {
    fields: image
  }, err => {...})   
})
```

**tested mongoose**

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(base64_file_data, (err, result) => {

  var newMyModel = new MyModel.model(model_data);

  newMyModel.image = result;

  newMyModel.save(err => {...})   
})
```